# Terminate a background page

Tags: google-chrome

I'm in the process of cleaning up the memory usage of Google Chrome and encountered a process called `Background Page: xxx`* which is racking up a lot of memory. As this [very useful** guide](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1184722?hl=en) points out, there is a button to end the process, but it still opens the next time I boot Chrome.

Is there a way to get rid of the background page entirely?

Footnote 1:
The running background page is **Google Drive**. When I terminate the process I get a Chrome notification that the app crashed. Google Drive is shown in the Notifications Settings but notifications are turned off. I couldn't find any other references to this app in the interface.

Footnote 2:
Select *Quit Google Chrome* to disable background apps? If you explain it to me in a 3-step process I do get tempted to try that option.